# montage: distortion filter on the combined images

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-montage

I am using the Montage of Image magick to combine all images contained *chicont* pattern and form 3 row grid composed of the fused images:

```
montage "${my_images}"/*chicont.png -geometry 1200 -tile x3e -mattecolor DarkGoldenrod2 -mode Frame -distort BarrelInverse 3:30 output_grid.png
```

By means of the option `-distort BarrelInverse 3:30` each combined image is distorted so the combined image would consist of many distorted parts assembled together.

Would it be possible to apply such distortion selectively on some images located in various places of the resulted combined image ? So the expected output image would contain only several distorted images mixed with the images added to the grid without distortion ?

Comment: `x3e` is not valid. Did you mean `x3`?  Also `3:30` is not valid either. I have never seen the colon ":" used as a separator in the barrelInverse distort command. The only way that I know to distort unique images is to distort them first with convert and then pipe all your images to montage.

Comment: well in that case the script works correctly with the exemption that it apply the filter on ALL images at once :-) so basically in order to apply its selectively I need to make a more complex bash script with the indication of the list of the images that should be distorted first, right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I just wonder to know more about application of the -distort filter. why the 3:30 was not correct (it works OK in my case ) ?? would it be possible to have some examples ?? thank you!!

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#barrelinverse